# Can i connect battery directly to motor

Tags: dc-motor, h-bridge

I want to drive two same 24v 5A(full load) Dc motors with pwm using 2 hbridges for each motor. I have two 12v 18Ah sealed lead acid batteries which will be in series to make 24v. 
Can i connect batteries directly to h-bridge or should i use a current regulator or any other circuitry between the battery and the driver circuit.

Comment: How are you going to generate your PWM?

Comment: Using atmega 16 microcontroller ic

Comment: So what is "directly" in your terminology? Schematic please.

Comment: By the word "directly" i ment connecting the terminals of the battery (combined in series) to h-bridge.

Comment: I would say "yes", but the lack of the full picture voids the warranty.

Comment: 12V + 12V = 24V. 24V is what the motors want. I can't think of any other way of wiring them up...

Comment: Is there any possibility that my motor draw too much current and damage itself if i connect tge battery without any regulators

Comment: The transistors in the H-Bridge will happily sacrifice themselves to protect the motor.  :)

Comment: @Sabheeh Ali: Your motor can draw toom much current if it is blocked or similar. But in that case it is not because of lack of voltage regulator. Motors in house appliances, battery powered tools or similar are all powered without voltage regulator. In fact, it is very rare to see voltage regulator between battery and motor, unless voltage need to be changed.

Comment: One thing i forgot to mention was that, i am using these motors in a wheelchair to drive the wheels

Answer (score 1):

Yes. No need for voltage regulator or similar. Voltage would be ~24V minus some voltage drop on transistors on H-bridge, so it is safe for motor, because this is the voltage the motor is rated for.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you can connect your batteries to your H-bridge directly. However, it also depends on what you are really trying to do. If you are just generating PWM for your motors (without ANY feedback, such as encoders) then as your batteries discharge you will see lower performance of your motors - for example lower revolutions per minute.

Let's say at 24V and 80% PWM you have ~100RPM's. As your batteries discharge, at 20V and still 80% PWM you might have 80 RPM's or less momentum (we don't know what you are trying to do with your motors).

The drawback of powering H-bridge directly from power source is that the motor performace is dependend on the battery voltage and you might want to use any feedback, for example an encoder to measure RPM's. When your battery level drops -> your RPM's drop then you just increase your PWM to keep RPM's at constant desired level.